# Using ensureIndex for locations in publications in Meteor

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, geospatial

I am currently trying to only pull collections that are near the user.  I have been able to successfully do this on the client with some of my other collections, but am struggling to accomplish it in publications.

I have the following code in my `server/index.js`:

```
Events._ensureIndex({'loc.coordinates':'2dsphere'});
```

And the following in my `server/publications.js`:

```
Meteor.publish('allEventsNearMe', function() {
  if (!this.userId) return null;
  var user = Meteor.users.findOne(this.userId);
  var home = Homes.findOne(user.profile.homeId);
  return Events.find({
    loc: {
      $near: {
        $geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: home.loc.coordinates // this is an array ex. [-80, 25]
        },
        $maxDistance:32187
      }
    }
  });
});
```

When I try to subscribe to this publication, I get the following error:

> Exception from sub allEventsNearMe id BDspYdPy6BG4RTP42 Error:
>   Exception while polling query
>   {"collectionName":"events","selector":{"loc":{"$near":{"$geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.26824199999999,26.123774]},"$maxDistance":32187}}},"options":{"transform":null}}:
>   Unable to execute query: error processing query: ns=meteor.events
>
> limit=0 skip=0 planner returned error: unable to find index for
>   $geoNear query

I have tried wrapping Events._ensureIndex in Meteor.startup, but that has not worked either. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try dropping the current index  and **[create the 2dsphere index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/2dsphere/#create-a-2dsphere-index)**, specifying the location field as the key not the coordinates array.

To first remove the index and keep your data you can connect to the mongo shell by typing the following into your terminal from your app's root directory (while meteor **is** running):

```
$ meteor mongo
```

Once you are in the shell, you can remove the index with this command:

```
> db.events.dropIndex({'loc.coordinates':1});
```

To create the "2dsphere" index on the "loc" field of your documents, try

```
> db.events.ensureIndex({'loc':'2dsphere'});
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. Create index in the shell didn't solve the problem in deployment. Only after I created a schema and attached it to the collection (using simple-schema and collection 2) I succeeded to use db._ensure Index in js file and it worked fine.